# Making a second Windows installation on macOS Catalina

Tags: windows, bootcamp, partition, ssd

I am trying to get a second Windows installation. I want this one to be unable to access the first Windows. I have looked at some threads but I can not understand what I need to do as they are all slightly different from one another and I dont understand them.

Here is my diskutil list. (Disk 2 is a USB with the ISO file and the Windows support files loaded from bootcamp. Bootcamp does not let me do a second Windows installation.)

```
/dev/disk0 (internal, physical):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *1.0 TB     disk0
   1:                        EFI EFI                     209.7 MB   disk0s1
   2:                 Apple_APFS Container disk1         499.0 GB   disk0s2
   3:       Microsoft Basic Data BOOTCAMP                501.0 GB   disk0s3

/dev/disk1 (synthesized):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      APFS Container Scheme -                      +499.0 GB   disk1
                                 Physical Store disk0s2
   1:                APFS Volume Mac SSD - Data          214.8 GB   disk1s1
   2:                APFS Volume Preboot                 24.9 MB    disk1s2
   3:                APFS Volume Recovery                526.8 MB   disk1s3
   4:                APFS Volume VM                      3.2 GB     disk1s4
   5:                APFS Volume Mac SSD                 11.2 GB    disk1s5

/dev/disk2 (external, physical):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:     FDisk_partition_scheme                        *30.9 GB    disk2
   1:               Windows_NTFS WinInstall              30.9 GB    disk2s1
```

Here is the `fdisk` output:

```
Disk: /dev/disk0    geometry: 121601/255/63 [1953525168 sectors]
Signature: 0xAA55
         Starting       Ending
 #: id  cyl  hd sec -  cyl  hd sec [     start -       size]
------------------------------------------------------------------------
 1: EE 1023 254  63 - 1023 254  63 [         1 -     409639] <Unknown ID>
 2: FF 1023 254  63 - 1023 254  63 [    409640 -  974610392] Xenix BBT
*3: 0B 1023 254  63 - 1023 254  63 [ 975020032 -  978503680] Win95 FAT-32
 4: 00    0   0   0 -    0   0   0 [         0 -          0] unused
```

Thanks.

Comment: What is the model/year of your Mac? Which version of Windows do you currently have installed? Which version of Windows do you what to install? Will you allocating space from the current Windows or from Catalina to create space for the new Windows partition?

Comment: @DavidAnderson Model: Late-2012 iMac, 21.5". Currently have Windows 10 Pro installed. Would like a second windows 10 installation. I have space to allocate from either one, but I was wanting to allocate space from Catalina. (Also Idk if this is relevant but the drive is the Samsung 980 EVO 1TB SSD). Thanks.

Comment: Post the output from the command `sudo fdisk /dev/disk0`. Have you considered using a virtual machine instead of installing a second Windows? I ask because to do so would probably be simpler.

Comment: @DavidAnderson here is the Fdisk output:

`Disk: /dev/disk0 geometry: 121601/255/63 [1953525168 sectors]
Signature: 0xAA55
         Starting       Ending
 #: id  cyl  hd sec -  cyl  hd sec [     start -       size]
------------------------------------------------------------------------
 1: EE 1023 254  63 - 1023 254  63 [         1 -     409639] <Unknown ID>
 2: FF 1023 254  63 - 1023 254  63 [    409640 -  974610392] Xenix BBT   
*3: 0B 1023 254  63 - 1023 254  63 [ 975020032 -  978503680] Win95 FAT-32
 4: 00    0   0   0 -    0   0   0 [         0 -          0] unused  ` 

(1/2)

Comment: @DavidAnderson I can not use a virtual machine as my computer does not have enough power to run a windows vm smoothly. I want to be able to play games on the second Windows installation and I can not do that with a VM. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

During 2012 model year, Apple started shipping iMacs without Optical drives. Also, Apple started transitioning to (U)EFI booting of Windows. However, your Mac was designed to legacy BIOS boot all Windows installations.

Note: This method of installation may require temporary use of a wired keyboard and/or wired mouse.

### Use macOS Catalina to create a Windows 10 installation flash drive.

To test this answer, the Windows 10 iso file `Win10_22H2_English_x64v1.iso` was downloaded from this Microsoft [website](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10ISO). For a Late 2012 iMac, the Windows 10 install disk can be created by the Boot Camp Assistant. Below is a snapshot of contents of this flash drive.

[image: flash drive]

### Create a partition for the second Windows installation.

When testing, the Disk Utility application included with Catalina (macOS 10.15.7) had a tendency to fail, when attempting to shrink the `Apple_APFS` partition and add a new ExFAT formatted `Microsoft Basic Data` partition. Therefore, this answer recommends using the `diskutil` command to accomplish this task. For example, to shrink a 499.0 GB `Apple_APFS` partition to approximately 300 GB and make a new `Windows` named partition of about 199 GB, the following command would need to be entered.

```
diskutil apfs resizecontainer disk0s2 300G exfat Windows 0
```

Note: This command will leave `disk0` hybrid partitioned.

### Make Windows the default to boot and boot to Windows.

This can be done by either of two ways given below.

- From the Startup Disk pane of the System Preferences application.
- By holding down the <kbd>control</kbd> key while selecting `Windows` from the Mac Startup Manager.

### BIOS boot from the flash drive.

Restart the Mac, then hold down the <kbd>option</kbd> key until the Mac Startup Manager icons appear. Boot from the flash drive by selecting the external (or flash) drive icon labeled `Windows`.

### Install Windows 10.

Proceed with the installation until a display similar to the one shown below appears.

[image: before]

1. Select the partition named `Drive 0 Partition 3: Windows`.
2. Format the partition. The Windows label will be removed. The display should now appear similar to the one shown below.

[image: after]

3. Procced with the installation of Windows to this partition.